# Putting an icon and an input on single ant design Form.Item

Tags: forms, antd

I have an ant design table. One of its columns is something like this:

[image: screenshot]

which contains three icons and one "AutoComplete" component showing some names. In editing mode, I have put all these four components ( 3 icons and one autocomplete) in a "Form.Item" tag. But the autocomplete component does not work properly in editing mode.( I mean when it is clicked for edit, the name inside it is cleared and the new selected name will not put in autocomplete input). But when I remove the three icons from the code, the autocomplete works fine.

Why this happens? can any body help on this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `Form.Item` need to have one child element because he implicitly pass to child `value` and `onChange` props. You probalby can create wrapper for your Autocomplete component, something like following (it's just idea):

```js
function Autocomplete (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon1/>
      <Icon2/>
      <Icon3/>
      <AntdAutocomplete value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange}/>
    <div/>
  );
}
```